# What are these light like panels on the overhead bins of Boeing 737?

Tags: boeing-737, cabin-design

These light like panels are seen in older Boeing 737s. I've never seen them turn on. Could someone enlighten (no pun intended).

[image]

Comment: I'd take a wild guess and say they're emergency lighting. There is lighting along the floor, including red lights at the exits, so you can see where to go if the cabin is filled with smoke, but if it's a "simple" power failure on the ground and it's dark outside, these may come on so people can see to walk out of the plane in a non-critical-emergency scenario. Much like the emergency lighting in a building - the batteries are charging while normal power is available, and as soon as that's gone, these come one.

Comment: Similar [1](https://www.airlines-inform.com/upload/reviews_pictures/1200-upload-blog-e08-miat-8.jpg) -- [2](https://1v7mh43xejam2hi9m11cptux-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/copa-airlines-1876.jpg).

Comment: @mins Thanks for those pics, I couldn't get a better one.

Answer (score 3):

They are indeed emergency cabin lighting. See, for instance, [this photo](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/7951666) of a similarly configured 737 interior.
[image]
(Łukasz Stawiarz - JetPhotos.net)

Comment: Thanks for the image. Do you have any further info as to how they are operated? Do they turn on automatically or activated by pilot/crew? Do they have a different power source?

Comment: They are manually operated or armed by the crew and have their own DC battery system.